# Resize text-size responsively so that it is showed on the same line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a navigation guide of my site whith anchors which I want to be displayed on the same line. On computers there is no problems as the width of the screen is bigger than the length of my text (only 5 words), but on mobile phones the text writes on two differents lines.

I have tried to add the CSS property `white-space: nowrap;` to the div containing the text but with this the part of the text that doesn't fit on the line simply would disapper by the overflow of the page. Is there a way to combine this property with another one so that if the text doesn't fit on one line the size of the text decrease to a size which would fit?

I'm using BootStrap 4 btw.

HTML

```
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mb-5">
             <div class="col-12 nowrap">
                 <a class="mr-1 noDecoration" href="tienda.php">Tienda</a> > <a class="mx-1 noDecoration" href="tienda.php#sudaderaIcon">Sudaderas</a> > <span class="ml-1">Sudadera Tape Verde</span>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.noDecoration, .noDecoration:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code too

Comment: Can you post html which includes wrapper of the text? (few levels would be better)

Comment: If you know the length of the text you can use font-size: [value]vw;

Comment: Srry, I just added the code involved by the problem

Comment: Its not showing your problems..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [media queries](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to change the font size base on screen width

```
@media screen and (max-width : 320px)
{
  #your-element
  {
    font-size:7px; /* or 1em */
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width : 1204px)
{
  #your-element
  {
    font-size:16px;
  }
}
```

You can also try vw, vh, vmin mentioned [here](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/), but its not widely supported.

Comment: Finally I had to do it with media queries, tried implementing vw units but on  mobile phones text was being displayed too small and it almost couldn't be read. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, see the snippet in `full-page` and resize the browser window

```css
.nowrap {
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 14px; // Added
    font-size: 3.4vw;  // Added
  }

.noDecoration, .noDecoration:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 14px; // Added
    font-size: 3.4vw; // Added  
  }
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mb-5">
             <div class="col-12 nowrap">
                 <a class="mr-1 noDecoration" href="tienda.php">Tienda</a> > <a class="mx-1 noDecoration" href="tienda.php#sudaderaIcon">Sudaderas</a> > <span class="ml-1">Sudadera Tape Verde</span>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/keuchhkx/1/)

Comment: I was thinking on using something this method until I read that this units have several compatibility problems, do you know how true is this?

Comment: it supports 93.93%, please check https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. 
This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. 
There is no obligation to do this. :) @Luiscri